# Bubble-sort issue n Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a linked list using bubble sort. However, it only goes through the list one time no fully sorting it.

```py
    listLen = GetLength(L)
    t = L.head
    for i in range(listLen - 1):
        if t.data > t.next.data:
            t.next.data, t.data = t.data, t.next.data
        t = t.next
```

Using list 11,2,5,8,3,10,9,1 my output is 2 5 8 3 10 9 1 11.

Answer (score 0):

Lets code this using my example:

a = [16, 19, 11, 15, 10, 12, 14]

repeating loop len(a)(number of elements) number of times

for j in range(len(a)):

```
#initially swapped is false

swapped = False
i = 0
while i<len(a)-1:
    #comparing the adjacent elements
    if a[i]>a[i+1]:
        #swapping
        a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]
        #Changing the value of swapped
        swapped = True
    i = i+1
#if swapped is false then the list is sorted
#we can stop the loop
if swapped == False:
    break
```

print (a)

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops for bubble sort

```
listLen = GetLength(L)
for i in range(listLen - 1):
    t = L.head
    for n in range(listLen - 1):
        if t.data > t.next.data:
            t.next.data, t.data = t.data, t.next.data
        t = t.next
```

Comment: This gives me the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: @CarlosC edited the answer, should work now. You’ll have to start at the head of the list at the beginning of each outer loop. You might also need to add in some logic in case you switch the first two elements, since you’ll be swapping the head for a new one. The list itself might take of that, so you’ll have to figure that out